# Interspire email marketer

Tags: html, email, client, src

I am working in interspire email marketer for creating e-mail news template ( e- updates). I used to construct those pages with table in HTML, and imported images with 'img src' tag within a 'td'
. When I send this email news letter to my mail account via interspire all the images are blocked by the mail application say for eg 'hotmail'. Its shows a message 'Attachments, pictures and links in this message have been blocked for your safety. Show content.' Is there any process to allow this e-Updates to show all pictures and images without needing a download function or any way to  construct a template by embedding the images or
cleaning the HTML so it can slip through firewalls.

Anyone please give some tips for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the product you are using, but this looks like the E-Mail fetches its images from an online resource (i.e. your server).

You would have to make your program actually *attach* all the displayed images to the E-Mail.

Comment: That said, this is not really a programming question :) Voting to migrate to Superuser.com. No need to do anything - if five votes accumulate, it will be moved there

Comment: I am using ' interspire email marketer' to send these templates. Here I schedule an email template to some mail account. When it comes to my mail its shows like this. Images are fetched from the server. Is there any way to unblock it other than changing the email application settings. Is it because of the ' image src' tag in HTML code which gets blocked, any alternative for this?

Comment: @user You will have to make your program actually attach all the displayed images to the E-Mail. That's all I can tell you. I don't know the program so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Pekka>> Thanks for your response :).I will try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I use enterspire, and i know there is a way. I don't know if you still trying to do this, but if anyone needs here it goes.

You can do this by selecting the option "Yes, embed images in the content", it appears in the penultimate step of the sending process.

I hope it helps you!
 Bye!